# How to render a view inside of another view (rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, view, controllers, partials

Hi I want to preface this by saying that I am new to coding.

I have an issue that I believe can be solved in two ways

A. by rendering a partial

B. by updating the controller

( I can totally be wrong but these are what I suspect lol)

I have two controllers/views "reviews" and "logs". and I want them to both appear on the same page.

How can I do this?
I tried rendering a partial but I alway get an error.

and I tried the piece of code below:

which made my reviews show up on the page, but when I add

```
@log = @user.logs.all
```

to it, it doesn't pull all the logs to the page like it does for the reviews.

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_name(params[:id])
  if @user 
    @reviews = @user.reviews.all
    render action: :show
  else
    render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [html]
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Alicia. Your question seems interesting, but your formatting isn't very clear and making it a little confusing. You'll get better chances at a good answer if you can edit your question and clarify that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First things first. Views refer to actions in controllers. So there can be several views for each controller or even none.

So, if you want to render `@reviews` and `@logs` on the same page you should first instantiate both instance variables in the same action and then render both partials in the same action.
How do you do that? Easy.
First you got to the controller you just showed and edit that `show` action.

```
def show       
  # You can set the variable in the if-clause 
  # And you also need to use static finders with a hash as an argument in Rails4
  if (@user = User.find_by(name: params[:id]))
     @reviews = @user.reviews.all 
     @logs = @user.logs.all
  # You don't need to call render explicitly 
  # if you render the view with the same name as the action 
   else
     render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [html]
   end     
end
```

Second: you go to your `/app/views/reviews/show.html.erb` template and put both partials there like this (this is just an example, adjust your markup to fit your needs).

```
<h1> Reviews and Logs</h1>
<div id="reviews_part">
 <%= render @reviews %>
</div>
<div id="logs_part">
  <%= render @logs %>
</div>
```

Now create 2 new partials `/app/views/reviews/_review.html.erb` and `/app/views/logs/_log.html.erb` and put all the needed markup there (use regular variables `review` and `log` to adress the repeating objects). Rails will automaticaly repeat those partials as many times as needed.

Or you can explicitely call the partial render

```
<div id="reviews_part">
  <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
   <%= render review %> 
        which is the same as
   <%= render partial:"reviews/review", locals:{review:review} %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing on the home page,which is the reviews index (the previous one you helped with got the reviews and logs successfully on the profile page). The same method you suggested isn't working for the index review page

Comment: Well, I suppose that on the index page you'll need to do `@reviews = Review.all` and `@logs = Log.all` 'cause you don't have a users name in the params.

Comment: when I just add that on the reviews index page I get the following error:                                                        ArgumentError in Reviews#index
Showing 

'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way of rendering partials into views in HAML:

```
=render :partial => "header"
%h2 Hello World
=render :partial => "footer"
```

Every partial you render this way, has to be created within the same folder.
Each partial's name has to begin with an underscore (*_*). This should be the view's directory:

```
- home
    - index.html.haml
    - _header.html.haml
    - _footer.html.haml
```